# Black screen flickering after update to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, graphics, screen, 22.04, flicker

I've been using 20.04 and I updated to 22.04. After a few days a black flickering appears randomly, it's very annoying and it didn't happen before. Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the exact same issue. I attempted to enable and dissable Wayland in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` but that made no difference.

Comment: Why can't you wait to August to upgrade to the stable version when it is released?

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm glad that it seems not to be a hardware issue, as you're also experiencing after 22.04 update.

Comment: same here on dell laptop latitude with intel HD integrated GPU. This flickering display stops when I move my mouse and come back sometimes on certain mouse position then disapear again on mouse move.

Comment: hey guys, same problem here. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970426. There are some possible config solutions posted there, and hopefully an official fix is gonna be released soon!

Answer (score 4):

A fix would be to add the following parameters to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
i915.enable_dc=0
intel_idle.max_cstate=2
```

then update GRUB using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You should be flicker-free now!

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970426/comments/24

Comment: Thank you, tried this! And thank you for the source, I'll also be checking there whether they have any information on this bug

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: @Scientist bug is still unresolved on the launchpad link provided above

Comment: Because I was struggling in which format I should add this parameter: It comes in one line separated by a space and in "" so : "i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2"

Comment: I'm on 22.04 and the proposed solution didn't work for me. Following the ticket, I tried another solution -- appeanding `i915.enable_psr=0` instead. I've been restarted for about 30 mins and it seems like it has worked. I found that solution here: https://github.com/ljvmiranda921/comments.ljvmiranda921.github.io/issues/41#issuecomment-1304393287